# Add OData Route During Runtime

Tags: c#, reflection, routes, odata

Is it possible to add OData Routes after the program is compiled?  For example, if I want to be able to get a property without using `$select`, I would need to add the attribute `[ODataRoute("Controller({key})/Property")]` to the `GET` method.  If I use reflection to get all of the property names, is it possible to create an ODataRoute like the above example without explicitly doing so in an attribute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible and there is a sample in the ODataSamples project for DynamicEdmModelCreation [here](https://github.com/OData/ODataSamples/tree/master/WebApi/v4/DynamicEdmModelCreation) to give an example of how this can work

It revolves around using the `ODataConventionModelBuilder` to generate your model at runtime like this:

```
var builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
builder.EntitySet<Customer>("Customers");
config.Routes.MapODataServiceRoute("odata", "odata", builder.GetEdmModel());
```